# Sequence.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listenerCount') using node javascript in browser

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I tryed implementing databases in my project , to make it clear is a simple login page. and i tryed implementig it in typescript in the main ,the code for the usage of  the database and main is this:

```
import { createPool } from "mysql";


export default function Ritorno(pis, palle) {
    
    const pool= createPool({
        host:"localhost",
        user:"root",
        password:"",
        database:"test",
        connectionLimit: 10
    })
    
    var pis="pis";
    var palle="palle"
    
    men="INSERT INTO `login`(`Username`, `Password`) VALUES ('"+pis+"','"+palle+"')";
    
    
    
    pool.query(men,(err,result,fields)=>{
        if(err){
            if(err.code=='ER_DUP_ENTRY'){
                console.log("pise")
            }
            //return console.log(err);
    
        }
        return console.log(result);
    })
    }



MAIN

import './login.css';
import { getTranslation } from '../backend/languageManager';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Ritorno from "./database";
// Quando la lingua cambia, impostala nel modulo di gestione delle lingue



const Login = ({ onLogin }: { onLogin: (usernameEmail: string, password: string) => void }) => {
    const [usernameEmail, setUsernameEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const [goToHomePage, setGoToHomePage] = React.useState(false);

    if (goToHomePage) {
        return <Navigate to='/homepage' />
    }

    const handleLogin = () => {
        console.log("Username/Email:", usernameEmail);
        console.log("Password:", password);
        Ritorno(usernameEmail,password);
        setGoToHomePage(true);
    };

    const handleContinueAsGuest = () => {
        setGoToHomePage(true);
    };


    return (
        <div className="login-container">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <div className="input-container">
                <label htmlFor="usernameEmail">Username/Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="usernameEmail"
                    value={usernameEmail}
                    onChange={(e) => setUsernameEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <div className="input-line"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container">
                <label htmlFor="usernameEmail">Password</label>
                <input type="text" id="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                <div className="input-line"></div>
            </div>
            <div className='centered-content'>
                <button className="login-button" onClick={handleLogin}>
                    {getTranslation('login')}
                </button>
                <button className="guest-button" onClick={handleContinueAsGuest}>
                    {getTranslation('continueAsGuest')}
                </button>
            </div>
            {/* Altri elementi del form di login */}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;

function setGuestView(arg0: boolean) {
    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
}
```

I tryed everything i knwo that the require method is not usable in the browser but almost every database is built with require nodes, should i change by hand the all the nodes to import? this is the full error code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listenerCount')
    at node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js (Sequence.js:8:34)
    at __require (chunk-UXIASGQL.js?v=672b4a04:8:50)
    at node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/ChangeUser.js (ChangeUser.js:1:16)
    at __require (chunk-UXIASGQL.js?v=672b4a04:8:50)
    at node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/index.js (index.js:1:22)
    at __require (chunk-UXIASGQL.js?v=672b4a04:8:50)
    at node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js (Protocol.js:2:20)
    at __require (chunk-UXIASGQL.js?v=672b4a04:8:50)
    at node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js (Connection.js:6:24)
    at __require (chunk-UXIASGQL.js?v=672b4a04:8:50)
```

Comment: I absolutely wouldn't expect a database Node module to work *in the browser*.

Comment: Where is `listenerCount` being accessed?

Comment: in the node module of mysql